# How to include a category level with NA observations in barplot

Tags: r

I want to display a plot in R which shows some areas that we did not received any data. So, I would like/need to display those areas included in a plot without data available, so that we can show in a report that we did not received information. I have done this in Excel (see attached) and would like to do it in R.

Below, find the code I have started to do in R but when I run it's displays an error:

```
lags = c(15, 24, 34, 44,54,64,68,70,72,74,76,78)                                
hf = c(2.56,2.16,4.23,0.00,2.73,,,,10.81,3.13,16.67,10.34)                       
district = c(2.56,2.16,21.69,0.00,2.73,,,,10.81,2.34,33.33,7.76)                      
province = c(2.56,2.16,21.69,0.00,2.73,,,,10.81,2.34,33.33,7.76)
deviation = matrix(c(hf,district,province), nrow=length(lags), ncol=3, 
                    dimnames=list(lags, c("hf","district","province")))         
# Create a matrix deviation with the data  
deviation1 = t(deviation)                             # Transpose the deviation matrix  


#par(mfrow = c(1, 1))                                   # Open a new window for the plot  
par(las=1,cex.axis=0.9,cex=0.9,cex.lab=0.9,cex.main=0.9,lwd=1)
bp2 <- barplot(deviation1,                             # Data (bar heights) to plot  
               beside=TRUE,                            # Plot the bars beside one another; default is to plot stacked bars  
               space=c(0.2,0.8),                       # Amount of space between i) bars within a group, ii) bars between groups  
               names.arg=c("Prov1", "Prov2", "Prov3", "Prov4", "Prov5","Prov6","Prov7", "Prov8", "Prov9", "Prov10",
                           "Prov11", "Prov12"),    #Names for the bars  
               col=c("yellow4","orange1","darkred"),             # Color of the bars  
               border="black",                         # Color of the bar borders  
               main=c(""),                     # Main title for the plot   Método utilizado
               xlab="",                                # X-axis label  
               ylab="",                                # Y-axis label  
               font.lab=2, ylim=c(0,100))              # Font to use for the axis labels: 1=plain text, 2=bold, 3=italic, 4=bold italic  

legend("topleft",                                      # Add a legend to the plot  
       legend=c("Health Facility","District","Province"),              # Text for the legend  
       fill=c("yellow4","orange1","darkred"),bty = "n", cex=0.8) # Fill for boxes of the legend  
text(x=bp2,2,y=c(deviation1[1:36]),labels=c(deviation1[1:36]),cex=0.8,pos=3)


 Error in c(2.56, 2.16, 4.23, 0, 2.73, , , , 10.81, 3.13, 16.67, 10.34) : 
      argument 6 is empty
```

Attached the figure generated in Excel: [figure 1 - deviations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcL2u.png)

Thank you in advance for your help.

Regards,
Rungo.

Comment: That error is just from reading in your data.  Change the gaps to NAs - e.g. `hf = c(2.56,2.16,4.23,0.00,2.73,NA,NA,NA,10.81,3.13,16.67,10.34)`

Comment: Thank you Andrew! Now it's working.